# Need sql to generate output as shown in expected results

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Customer | Add Seq | City     | Phone
Test1    | 1       |Delhi     | 1231
Test1    | 2       |Noida     | 2334
Test2    | 1       |Bengaluru | 3333
Test2    | 2       |Noida     | 3333
Test2    | 3       |Chennai   | 5565
Test3    | 2       |Chennai   | 5565
Test4    | 1       |Noida     | 3333
Test4    | 2       |Chennai   | 5565
Test5    | 1       |Chennai   | 5565
```

Need all customer rows, having both Noida and Chennai address

Expected Result:

```
Test2    | 2       |Noida     | 3333
Test2    | 3       |Chennai   | 5565
Test4    | 1       |Noida     | 3333
Test4    | 2       |Chennai   | 5565
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2):

A simple method uses `exists`.  For just two addresses:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.city in ('Noida', 'Chennai') and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.customer = t.customer and
                    t2.city in ('Noida', 'Chennai') and
                    t2.city <> t.city
             );
```

Comment: Doesn't show all the rows of a customer, only those two having 'Noida' or 'Chennai' city

Comment: @Tejash: Obviously, without the `t2.city <> t.city`, the subquery would find the outer row again, therefore showing all rows with Noida or Chennai, no matter if there is a second entry with the other city or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the windows function

```
select * from
(select t.*, count(distinct city) over (partition by customer) as cnt
from your_Table t
where city in ('Noida','Chennai')
) where cnt = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table 
WHERE Customer IN (
  SELECT Customer 
  FROM your_table 
  WHERE City IN ('Noida', 'Chennai')
  GROUP BY Customer
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT City) = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the results you want you need to select all data where city is 'Noida' or 'Chennai', and customer is 'Test2' or 'Test4':

```
SELECT *
  FROM TEST_DATA
  WHERE CITY IN ('Noida', 'Chennai') AND
        CUSTOMER IN ('Test2', 'Test4')
  ORDER BY Customer
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c65aa9a9824857194e99abd2a7b74d1)